# See only the commits created on a branch, with merged commits hidden

Tags: git, git-log

I'd like to be able to see the commits that have been created on a branch, but without any of the commits that have been merged on to it from other branches. Something like `git log`, but with activity on other branches either completely hidden, or abbreviated to a single entry noting that a merge was made.

Comment: I didn't word my comment very well. I deleted it, if I can think of a better way to say this I will post another one or else an answer...

Comment: Heh, thanks @DanLowe, I was going to reply. I understand the point that you made, by the way – I appreciate that those commits are now on this branch having been merged there. I will want to see able to ignore them, though. I want to see just the commits that were created on this branch rather than commits that were merged to this branch. I've edited a little for clarity.

Comment: I get what you want, just don't know if it's possible. A branch is just a pointer to a commit, so short of tracking parentage in the graph, I'm not sure git even keeps track of where a thing was first committed, in the case of cherry-picks and such.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you right, I think you may be looking for

```
git log --no-merges
```

However, this only filters out commits with more than one parent. If something was merged to this branch via cherry-pick or fast-forward merge, they will probably still show up unless they had multiple parents for another reason.

Comment: Ah. This helps (thanks), but I think because of the fast-forward thing it's of limited use. I'm certainly still seeing lots of commits that weren't made on this branch.

Comment: mMmm – `--first-parent` as a further additional flag seems to possibly show me what I want to see…